# lpadmin add a network printer

Tags: cups

I am having problems configuring a laserjet printer using lpadmin.

I am using the following command:

```
$ lpadmin -p LaserJet -E -v socket://10.1.1.1 -m laserjet.ppd
lpadmin: Unable to copy PPD file.
```

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ulpadmin.htm

```
$ find /| grep laserjet.ppd (returns nothing)
```

I understand this means the ppd driver file does not exist yet the following does not identify a driver for my printer:

```
$ lpinfo --make-and-model "Laserjet Pro M402dn" -m
lpinfo: client-error-not-found
```

On my Ubuntu desktop I am using the M806 driver to print to this printer so:

```
$ lpinfo --make-and-model "Laserjet M806" -m
HP/hp-laserjet_m806-ps.ppd.gz HP LaserJet M806 Postscript (recommend)
```

Now the following does not produce an error:

```
$ lpadmin -p LaserJet -E -v socket://10.1.1.1 -m HP/hp-laserjet_m806-ps.ppd.gz
```

To verify the printer has been created I ran the following:

```
$ lpstat -d 
system default destination: Laserjet
$ lpstat -p
printer laserjet@ts_6666 unknown state. enabled since Jun 22...
Printer: laserjet@tx_6666 - ERROR: spool queue for 'laserjet' does not exist on server ts_6666
check for correct printer name or you may need to run 
'checkpc -f' to create queue
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit older, and I hope you resolved it in the meantime, but for others who find this question:

The problem is likely that the package that contains your PPD file has not been installed. Not being familiar with Ubuntu, I can't tell which package that is. On CentOS, it is probably hplip for HP printers. It could also be one of the foo* or foomatic* packages.